# Android: overridePendingTransition doesn't work with FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT

Tags: android, animation, transition

I have one Activity that is launched with `FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT`, I used it to set Activity always active in the app. And when `FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT` is activated `overridePendingTransition` doesn't work, I guess that is because the Activity is already opened and `overridePendingTransition`can't run it because of that. And my question is there have some way to activate animations.

Thanks in advance.

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Welcome.this, UploadsList.class);

            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();

            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.down_to_top1, R.anim.down_to_top2);
```

**Update!!!**

After long research I find a solution.

just I added in transition XML

```
android:zAdjustment="top"
```

and I activate `overridePendingTransition` with:

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.down_to_top1, R.anim.down_to_top2);
}
```

Comment: I can't believe I've never seen that property before, it opens up a lot of possibilities!